# What exactly means this type of generic usage (dot between function and generic): "var mf: MeshFilter = GetComponent.<MeshFilter>();"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I am newbie in C#. I am switching languages from Java to C# and I found different usage of generics. Can someone explain what this dot between function and generic means? What is a difference between function with generic that has this dot and that one without it?

I was searching in google what it may be but I did not find nothing like this. I was searching for it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-generics-introduction/ but without any result.

Here is the code that I do not understand:

```
function Start() {  
    var mf: MeshFilter = GetComponent.<MeshFilter>();
    ...
```

source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Example-CreatingaBillboardPlane.html

Comment: That's not C#, that's UnityScript, so of course you don't understand it as C#

Comment: what does this dot exactly mean?

Comment: I don't know, I don't know UnityScript. I would suggest you to get a UnityScipt tutorial if you would want to understand the basics. The C# version, however, would be `MeshFilter mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();`

Comment: I guess it is just the way Unity integrated generic into a language that does not support it.

Comment: You should actually notify Unity about that since they provide a UnityScript/JavaScript example though the support for UnityScript was/will be removed

Answer (score 0):

this isn't c# its something called unityscript, you can easily tell because when declaring a variable you can't have a ':' at the end of the variable name, and you cant specify a generic type after the '.' you have to specify it before, or in somecases the compiler will auto detect it based on the output, like how `Task.Run(()=>{return int.MaxValue; })` will be auto compleated by the compiler to 
`Task.Run<int>(()=>{return int.MaxValue;})`.